# Top tier publications for job application in the Czech Republic

Tags: publications, career-path, job-search

I am asked to provide my Tier 1,5,10 and 25 publications for a job application in the Czech Republic. Is there any standardized way how to interpret this? Does this refer to journals with impact factors > 5, > 10 etc. or does this rather refer to the number of citations for each of the relevant publications?

Maybe somebody can clear this up for me.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Maybe they are asking you for a list of the one (five, ten, twentyfive) of your publications that *you* consider the most important. I have seen similar requirements in Germany.

Comment: Thank you for the hint from Germany. I'm still not quite sure, what they mean though. Obviously a list of the 10 top publications also includes the 5 top publications and so on. The #1 publication would then show up in 4 lists. I just don't think that they want me to copy/paste these lists 5 times.

Comment: Have you tried asking them?

Comment: I don't have a personal contact there, just a generic submission email address, which might or might not be checked before the deadline. Apart from that, I'm not sure, how appropriate this would be or considered to be.

Comment: I contacted them in the meantime, so far without any response. If I do get feedback, I will post it here for clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got a response from them.

They asked me to provide the publication counts according to the journal impact factors or actually ranges of impact factors [1:5[, [5:10[ etc. One of the options I guessed anyway.

Maybe this still helps somebody in the future.